# Why are parallel tests failing with “Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError invalid session id”?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, circleci

I am testing a Rails app on CircleCI. I'm running parallel tests in separate containers.

```
#.circleci/config.yml
...
jobs:
  build:
    parallelism: 2
    ...
```

One container always fails with:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
              invalid session id
```

If I change configuration and only run 1 container, all my tests pass.

I guess I have configured something incorrectly for parallel testing. Can anyone help me to understand why Selenium might be expecting a session that does not exist, and where I should be looking to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem in selenium running in docker env. A way to fix it is use the `disable-dev-shm-usage` options and change the Capybara server port. Like it:

```rb
# ...

Capybara.server_port = 9887 + ENV["CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX"].to_i # In order to create a new server port to each runner

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  # ...
  browser_options.args << '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
  # ...
end
```

Source: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/issues/658#issuecomment-429395002

Comment: thanks @duke, this looks promising. What is `ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER']`? Is this a number representing the build (i.e., all containers have the same number)? Or a number representing the container?

Comment: It's a container index, in circle ci I believe you can use `ENV['CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX'], I changed  my answer to make it easy

Comment: thanks! I've been struggling with this issue for a while. Your answer seems to have solved it!